# asp.net - datagrid con varias coluimnas con links, y como procesar el evento de cada link

Tags: asp.net

como puedo hacer un datagrid de asp.net 2003 que tenga 6 columnas (aparte de las columnas de los datos) link en cada una de ellas, y lo que estoy mas perdido: Como proceso cada uno de los eventos de cada link? Gracias.

Comment: a que te refieres cuando dices "link en cada una de ellas" ? que control estas usando, es el GridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para crear las columnas adicionales solo debes definirlas en el diseño

[Creating Custom Columns for the ASP.NET Datagrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479316.aspx)

Imagino en tu grid defines la propiedad `AutoGenerateColumns` en true. Como observaras en el articulo hay varias formas de poder lograrlo

Podrias definir una columnas del tipo `HyperLinkColumn`

```
<asp:DataGrid id="DataGrid1" 
   runat="server"
   AutoGenerateColumns="true">
   <Columns>
      <asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlField="application_id" 
          DataNavigateUrlFormatString="applicationform.aspx?id={0}" 
          DataTextField="application_id" HeaderText="APPLICATION_ID"></asp:HyperLinkColumn>
   </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

En este caso seria un link en la columna que redirecciona a una url, es importante la propiedad `DataNavigateUrlField`

Otra alternativa seria usando `<asp:ButtonColumn>`.

```
<asp:DataGrid id="DataGrid1" 
   runat="server"
   AutoGenerateColumns="true">
   <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonColumn 
         HeaderText="Edit item" 
         ButtonType="LinkButton" 
         Text="Edit" 
         CommandName="Edit"/> 
   </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Puede definir varios ButtonColumn como necesites

La accion la recibes en el evento [ItemCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) donde tendras el `CommandName` para conocer que accion se pulso

Igual lo que aconsejaria es que si quieres darle una posicion concreta a estas columnas las definas todas en tiempo de diseño y asignes el `AutoGenerateColumns="false"`